# reference with constexpr causes multiple definition error

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I program for MCUs with CodeSourcery g++ lite which is based on gcc 4.7.2

I want to define peripheral objects which is located at certain address. So I try to use reference with the constexpr specifier.

for example:

```
typedef int& int_ref;
constexpr int_ref i = *(int*)0;
```

If I put that code into a header, and compile my program, I will get diagnosis like:

```
xx1.o:(.rodata.i+0x0): multiple definition of `i'
...
xxx.o:(.rodata.i+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It confuses me bacause the `constexpr int i = 5` goes so happily with the compiler.

Of course there are alternative solutions:

1. Macros,  `#define i *(int*)0`, which pollutes every .c/.cpp file including the header. Currently, I'm using macros.

2. static object, `static constexpr int_ref i = *(int*)0;`. Without some compiler-option (-fdata-sections), the compiler can't eliminate unused objects and then there would be lots of space wasted.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `*(int*)0;` is undefined behavior, isn't it?

Comment: @AndyPowl If I'm wrong, please tell me. '((SomeStruct*)address) -> member' is widely used in mcu programming. So I think '(*(SomeStruct*)address).member ' is OK too.

Comment: You are dereferencing a null pointer, this is undefined behavior. You can't dereference a pointer that doesn't point to any object.

Comment: @AndyPowl thanks, the '0' in the code represents a certain address just for demo.

Comment: What about just `constexpr int& i = *(int*)some_addr;` (i.e., without the extra `typedef`)?

Comment: @Xeo I tried. The same with my code.

Comment: In any case, `constexpr int& get_i(){ static constexpr int& i = *(int*)some_addr; return i; }` should work.

Comment: @Xeo Yes, I will work. But personally I don't like to use it this way.

Comment: Are you sure there is space wasted with `static constexpr int_ref i = *(int*)0;`? after all its constexpr. I can't test because I use GCC 4.6 which has this bug http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49172 but if I make a constexpr pointer and deref it I can only find its address in assembler at the site where I use it and nowhere else.