# C++ constexpr reference multiple definition

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm trying to use a constexpr reference pointer to an external defined object.

#### `hardware.h`

```
extern int crypticName;
```

#### `hardware.cpp`

```
#include "hardware.h"
int crypticName;
```

#### `shared.h`

```
#include "hardware.h"
constexpr int& usefulName = crypticName; // This is the reference I'm interested in
```

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include "shared.h"
int main() {return 0;}
```

#### `other.cpp`

```
#include "shared.h"
```

GCC doesn't seem to have a problem with the syntax used. However when the linker tries to bring everything together, I get a `multiple definition` problem.

```
.bld/other.cpp.o:(.rodata.usefulName+0x0): multiple definition of `usefulName'
.bld/main.cpp.o:(.rodata.usefulName+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm guessing that the compiler is guessing (or using some placeholder for) some location for `crypticName` in each compilation unit and loses the `extern` linkage that normally deals with these issues. So maybe this is expected behavior.

Is there some simple thing I'm missing? Or do I need to change how I'm abstracting my hardware?

One way to "solve" this is to use `constexpr int * const usefulName = crypticName` instead of the reference assignment. However, I'd prefer to not need to dereference `usefulName` all the time. After all, one of the points of this abstraction in my use case is to hide the pointer stuff.

Of note, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291867/reference-with-constexpr-causes-multiple-definition-error) might be the same.

Comment: You clearly have two definitions of `usefulName` (one in `main` unit and one in `other` unit)

Comment: Agree that it is the same as the question you linked, although that doesn't have an answer either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `usefulName` to be `static` explicitly to force it to have internal linkage:

```
static constexpr int& usefulName = crypticName;
```

I'm not sure why it isn't static by default, given that it's `constexpr`, but explicitly declaring it `static` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I guess it would be a compiler bug if the compiler gives it external linkage; [basic.link] seems very clear